# Angular2 Custom Component with bindable property - how to [(value)] without @Output in custom component?

Tags: data-binding, angular, angular2-components

I have a custom component with an input property as follows:

```
export class MyComponent{
     @Input() value:number;
}
```

So that I can plop one on a parent component:

```
<my-component [(value)]="someValueAtParentComponent"></my-component>
```

Note that I did not provide @Component decorator and the class for the parent component because I don't think those are relevant.

Now, things happen internally in MyComponent that can change the value of `value`.

From inside MyComponent's template, I display `{{value}}`, and it displays the correct value throughout its lifetime.

From the parent component's template, I display `{{someValueAtParentComponent}}`, but it doesn't update with MyComponent's value. I thought [(value)] will automatically do the job, but I guess not.

I don't want to create an `@Output` event on MyComponent for the parent component to handle the event where it would set `someValueAtParentComponent` explicitly.

I believe Angular wants to emit an event for a parent component to handle, but that seems very tedious. Is there something we can do in our own components so that we may use the syntactic sugar `[(value)]` instead of `[value]="..." (onValueChanged)="onValueChangedHandler($event)"`?